# Left panel is not taking full height, though height 100% is specified

Tags: html, css

Below is a screen shot of my window image after scrolling window
[image: screenshot]

I have given height of 45px to my header and for main section am using flex. Inside main section I have left-section and right-section. I want my left section to take full screen height whenever I minimize or maximize my window.

This is how my page looks when am scrolling. The left panel is not getting adjust with scrolling, though I have given height of 100%

HTML

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="main-section">
    <div class="left-section"></div>
    <div class="right-section"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
.main-section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.left-section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you post the full code?

Comment: JokerFan i have embedded the code

Comment: The code you shared is not enough to replicate the screenshot... What do you mean *"The left panel is not getting adjust with scrolling"* - How should it adjust? Do you want it to stay at the same position of screen even while scrolling?

Comment: Try `height:auto` for `left-section`

Comment: @TJ i want the left section to stick to bottom. I tried using Bottom :0 by making position as absolute, but all in vain

Comment: @Yashika Please update the question with code required to reproduce the screen shot and try to rephrase the question. *"This is how my page looks when am scrolling. The left panel is not getting adjust with scrolling"* - sounds like you need a scroller, but you commented you don't need a scroller.. :) In case if you didn't know, there is an option to include a live demo like JSFiddle when you're editing a question...

Answer (score 0):

Problem -

```
height : 100%
```

It refers to the height of Parent element (.main-section) and then sets height of the element(.left-section) to 100% of that. If the parent element's height is not set to anything then browser has nothing to refer to.

Solution - Set the height of .main-section then .left-section will take its height.

Hope this helps!!